# Is it possible to create pure namespace for css

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

My case is my website including lots of Javascript and CSS,

Is there anyway, to create a pure clean Namespace for a section in the index file.

When I put some tag like `<li>`, `<ol>`, or `<nav>` it shouldn't be affected by other loaded css files.(Because assets pipeline will automated load it)

But I still want other sections in the page has the style as original.

### Take the index.html.haml for example

```
link{href: "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css", rel: "stylesheet"}/
= render 'nav'
= render 'revolution_bar'
= render 'service'
/ I wanna create a clean space here
= render 'about_us'
```

Is there anyway to avoiding the Stylesheet to be polluted by other assets.

Answer (score 0):

[semantic ui](http://semantic-ui.com/) has this as part of their style guide: http://semantic-ui.com/guide/styleguide.html.

I do this a lot - it's sort of the way you create namespaces in JavaScript, in that you create an object (or in the case of css, a class) whose only purpose is to function as a namespace.

In semantic ui their top-level namespace is `ui`. As an example a selector for a menu item might be like this:

```
.ui.menu .item {
   ...
 }
```

The class `ui` class isn't actually applied on its own to any elements, its just used to prefix other classes.

Of course - your top level namespace class can be anything you like. But this should insulate any css code on the page, providing there isn't already a `ui` class on the page.

Is this what you are meaning?